# Autorotation on Win8.1

Tags: windows, registry, tablet, screen-rotation

I want to turn on resp. off the Autorotation-feature in Win8.1. pro grammatically (and not [like in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759020/windows-8-autorotation-registry-value) query it!) .

With ProcessMonitor I figured out, that when changing the DisplaySettings the following key is set:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation\Enable
```

when I do a change manually with regEdit (or PowerShell) then the change is not reflected in the system, i.e.

- the display-settings ignore manual changes (i.e. old value remains)
- rotation-changes on my tablet are ignored

Question:

Do I need to do any other special update? Or do I need to run the update differently? Or is the reg-key not valid?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone has the answer to this question?

I found out that changing the 'Enable' value works, but only if I first enable the "Allow the screen to auto-rotate" option in Control Panel/Screen Resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, here's the solution:

```
SETAUTOROTATION SetAutoRotation = (SETAUTOROTATION)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"user32.dll"), (LPCSTR)2507);
if (SetAutoRotation != nullptr)
{
    if (!SetAutoRotation(THE_SETTING))
    {
        // An error occurred
    }
}
```

Found on this post: [How to get the screen auto-rotate's status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793108/how-to-get-the-screen-auto-rotates-status)